# Mysql order based on sum result

Tags: mysql

I have a Mysql table with users playing as double partners in a tennis tournament and also a table with rankings in which every player has a ranking score in doubles matches.

Tournaments_registrations_doubles

| id | player1_id | player2_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 32 | 25 |
| 2 | 25 | 28 |
| 3 | 143 | 83 |

Rankings_doubles

| id | player_id | points |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 25 | 127 |
| 2 | 19 | 83 |
| 3 | 32 | 97 |
| 4 | 83 | 41 |

I am trying to build an SQL query that will get the ids of the Tournaments_registrations_doubles table in descending order based on the sum of the ranking points of each player group. So player_1 and player_2 who's sum of point in rankings table is highest should come first, and so on. Not all players are registered in the ranking table.
Any ideas on how to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the tournament table to the doubles table twice, once for each of the two player columns.  Then order the result set descending by the sum of points.

```sql
SELECT t.id, t.player1_id, t.player2_id,
       COALESCE(r1.points, 0) + COALESCE(r2.points, 0) AS total
FROM Tournaments_registrations_doubles t
LEFT JOIN Rankings_doubles r1 ON r1.player_id = t.player1_id
LEFT JOIN Rankings_doubles r2 ON r2.player_id = t.player2_id
ORDER BY COALESCE(r1.points, 0) + COALESCE(r2.points, 0) DESC;
```

Notice that we use left joins here, so that we may treat missing points as zero when computing the totals.

Comment: Tim thank you very much for your answer. However, are you sure the query will bring results in case one of the two players is not in the rankings table?

Comment: I run the query and it only gets results in case both players are in rankings table.

Comment: Your observations seem dubious to me, and I expect that my answer should at least report every record from the tournament table.  Are you certain that you are running my exact answer?

Comment: Sure Tim, Here is the query (copy paste) from my code
SELECT t.id, t.player1_id, t.player2_id,
COALESCE(r1.points, 0) + COALESCE(r2.points, 0) AS total
FROM tournaments_registrations t
LEFT JOIN rankings r1 ON r1.user_id = t.player1_id
LEFT JOIN rankings r2 ON r2.user_id = t.player2_id
where 
t.category_id=69 AND r1.type='d' and r2.type='d'
ORDER BY COALESCE(r1.points, 0) + COALESCE(r2.points, 0) DESC;

I only added a where clause which shouldn't affect the result. The tournaments_registrations table has also a "category" field and a rankings have a type (s=singles, d=doubles) match

Comment: That's **NOT** my query.  Move all criteria in the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clauses of the joins and it should work.

Comment: A yeap. I got it. That's where my mistake was. Sorry about that